# Should /usr owner be root?

Tags: files, permissions, opensuse, chown

After having installed the [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database on [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) I realized that for all files in `/usr/bin` the owner was changed to the "mysql" user of the "mysql" group. Maybe there was some mistake of mine. The worst problem was with the `/usr/bin/sudo` command, which obviously did not work, but I've taken back the ownership to *root* (having logged to *root*) and it is OK now.

Should I change owner of all files in `/usr/bin` to *root* or may this cause some malfunctioning of other programs? Should they also have the "Set UID" option marked in the Privileges tab as `sudo` does?

Comment: Please show us the current ownership. Your question is very unclear, files in `/usr` _should_ be owned by root, who is it that owns them now?

Comment: @terdon at the moment the owner of /usr/bin is the user "mysql" of "mysql" group and every file is "rwx r-x r-x"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us some examples. Your question states that "the owner was changed _to_ root", I assume you meant _from_ then?

Comment: They most certainly don't need the SUID bit with some very rare exceptions!

Comment: @terdon Ah, ok, sorry - I have edited. And this also concerns only /usr/bin, all others in /usr are owned by root (but I ask about them anyway)

Comment: This is one good reason to use a binary package. Was that not an option for you?

Comment: @FaheemMitha actually I did. I used YaST to install this (I am absolutely sure I haven't changed the ownerships manually) and I am afraid this will happen again.

Comment: @Voitcus Ok. In that case, file a bug report against the appropriate package. Better still, send a patch. If the packagers don't know something is wrong, they can't fix it.

Comment: I landed up in a similar situation, but I am unable to `su`. It says password incorrect. How did you get the sudo ownership back to root!

Comment: @Swanidhi I had this problem 2 years ago, I can't remember if I had any problems with `su`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all files under `/usr` should be owned by root, except that files under `/usr/local` may or may not be owned by root depending on site policies. It's normal for root to own files that only a system administrator is supposed to modify.

There are a few files that absolutely need to be owned by root or else your system won't work properly. These are [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) root executables, which run as root no matter who invoked them. Common setuid root binaries include [`su`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)) and [`sudo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) (programs to run another program as a different user, after authentication), `sudoedit` (a companion to `sudo` to edit files rather than run an arbitrary programs), and programs to modify user accounts (`passwd`, `chsh`, `chfn`).

In addition, a number of programs need to run with additional group privileges, and need to be owned by the appropriate group (and by the root user) and have the setgid bit set.

You can, and should, restore proper permissions from the package database. If you attempt to repair manually, you're bound to miss something and leave some hard-to-diagnose bugs lying around. Run the following commands:

```
rpm -qa | xargs rpm --setugids --setperms
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: See Gilles' answer for a way to fix the permissions and ownerships instead of trying to adjust based on my (for you probably incomplete) list.**

There are a few files that are normally owned by another group. Excerpt from my system:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.9 (squeeze)

$ find /usr/bin -not -group root -exec ls -g {} \; | awk '{print $NF,$3}'
/usr/bin/crontab crontab
/usr/bin/mlocate mlocate
/usr/bin/mutt_dotlock mail
/usr/bin/expiry shadow
/usr/bin/mail-unlock mail
/usr/bin/wall tty
/usr/bin/mail-touchlock mail
/usr/bin/bsd-write tty
/usr/bin/screen utmp
/usr/bin/dotlockfile mail
/usr/bin/chage shadow
/usr/bin/ssh-agent ssh
/usr/bin/mail-lock mail
```

Files with SUID bit:

```
$ find /usr/bin -perm -4000
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/sudoedit
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/sudo
```